# Exception handling in pipeline sequence

Tags: f#

I' working on a basic 2D CAD engine and the pipeline operator significantly improved my code. Basically several functions start with a point (x,y) in space and compute a final position after a number of move operations:

```
let finalPosition =
    startingPosition
    |> moveByLengthAndAngle x1 a1 
    |> moveByXandY x2 y2
    |> moveByXandAngle x3 a3
    |> moveByLengthAndAngle x4 a4
    // etc...
```

This is incredibly easy to read and I'd like to keep it that way. The various x1, a1, etc. obviously have a meaning name in the real code.

Now the new requirement is to introduce exception handling. A big try/with around the whole operation chain is not enough because I'd like to know which line caused the exception. I need to know which argument is invalid, so that the user knows what parameter must be changed.

For example if the first line (moveByLengthAndAngle x1 a1) raises an exception, I'd like to tell something like "Hey, -90 is an invalid value for a1! a1 must be between 45 and 90!". Given that many operations of the same type can be used in the sequence it's not enough to define a different exception type for each operation (in this example I wouldn't be able to tell if the error was the first or the last move).

The obvious solution would be to split the chain in single let statements, each within its respective try/with. This however would make my beautiful and readable code a bit messy, not so readable anymore.

**Is there a way to satisfy this requirement without sacrificing the readability and elegance of the current code?**

(note. right now every moveBy function raises an exception in case of errors, but I'm free to change for ex. to return an option, a bigger tuple, or just anything else if needed).

Comment: Can you not put the exception handling within each function?

Comment: Completely agree with Daniel. Especially if you ever reuse your functions, that's where the exception handling (and tagging) belongs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about folding over Choices? Let's say that instead of pipelining the actions, you represent them like this:

```
let startingPosition = 0. ,0.

let moveByLengthAndAngle l a (x,y) = x,y // too lazy to do the math
let moveByXandY dx dy (x,y) = 
    //failwith "oops"
    x+dx, y+dy
let moveByXandAngle dx a (x,y) = x+dx, y

let actions = 
    [
        moveByLengthAndAngle 0. 0., "failed first moveByLengthAndAngle"
        moveByXandY 1. 2., "failed moveByXandY"
        moveByXandY 3. 4., "failed moveByXandY"
        moveByXandAngle 3. 4., "failed moveByXandAngle"
        moveByLengthAndAngle 4. 5., "failed second moveByLengthAndAngle"
    ]
```

i.e. `actions` is of type `((float * float -> float * float) * string) list`.

Now, using [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) we lift the actions to Choice and fold/bind (<strike>not sure how to call it</strike> this is similar to [foldM in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#foldM)) over the actions:

```
let folder position (f,message) =
    Choice.bind (Choice.protect f >> Choice.mapSecond (konst message)) position

let finalPosition = List.fold folder (Choice1Of2 startingPosition) actions
```

`finalPosition` is of type `Choice<float * float, string>` , i.e. it's either the final result of all those functions, or an error (as defined in the table above).

Explanation for this last snippet:

- Choice.protect is similar to Tomas' protect, except that when it finds an exception, it returns the exception wrapped in a Choice2Of2. When there's no exception, it returns the result wrapped in a Choice1Of2.
- Choice.mapSecond changes this potential exception in Choice2Of2 with the error message defined in the table of actions. Instead of (konst message) this could also be a function that builds the error message using the exception.
- Choice.bind runs this "protected" action against the current position. It will not run the actual action if the current position is in error (i.e. a Choice2Of2).
- Finally, the fold applies all actions threading along / accumulating the resulting Choice (either the current position or an error).

So now we just have to pattern match to handle each case (correct result or error):

```
match finalPosition with
| Choice1Of2 (x,y) -> 
    printfn "final position: %f,%f" x y
| Choice2Of2 error -> 
    printfn "error: %s" error
```

If you uncomment `failwith "oops"` above, finalPosition will be a `Choice2Of2 "failed moveByXandY"`

Comment: Interesting approach! I think Tomas' solution is simpler though

Comment: I agree that Tomas' solution is simpler, but they actually do different things. When an error is found, Tomas assumes a default value and carries on executing the rest of the actions using this default value. This solution aborts on the first error, much like an exception. It's not really one better than the other, it depends on what behavior you need...

Comment: ok I get it, you're right. Picking your answer as it does /exactly/ what I asked.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori : you can send us any comments or questions about FSharpx through the google group: http://groups.google.com/group/fsharpx , or through stackoverflow, of course.

Comment: I expanded upon this in a recent blog post, explaining more in detail and comparing with other alternative solutions: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/11/few-fsharpx-examples.html

Answer (score 7):

The solution that Rick described is only going to handle exceptions that are raised when evaluating the *arguments* of the functions in the pipeline. However, it will not handle the exceptions that are raised by the pipelined functions (as described [in answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263115/why-does-pattern-matching-fail-on-an-exception-in-this-case)).

For example, let's say you have these simple functions:

```
let times2 n = n * 2
let plus a b = a + b
let fail n = failwith "inside fail"

10 // This will handle exception that happens when evaluating arguments
   |> try plus (failwith "evaluating args") with _ -> 0 
   |> times2                                            
   |> try fail with _ -> 0 // This will not handle the exception from 'fail'!
```

To solve this, you can write a function that wraps any other function in an exception handler. The idea that your `protect` function will take a function (such as `times2` or `fail`) and will return a new function that takes the input from the pipeline (number) and passes it to the function (`times2` or `fail`), but will do this inside exception handler:

```
let protect msg f = 
  fun n -> 
    try
      f n 
    with _ ->
      // Report error and return 0 to the pipeline (do something smarter here!)
      printfn "Error %s" msg
      0
```

Now you can protect each function in the pipeline and it will also handle exceptions that happen when evaluating these functions:

```
let n =
  10 |> protect "Times" times2
     |> protect "Fail" fail
     |> protect "Plus" (plus 5)
```

Comment: Ahh, you're right. It's fixed now but I feel awful for missing that. No more late-night StackOverflow for me :).

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of ways to approach this, the easiest would be to just wrap each call in a try-with block:

```
let finalPosition =
    startingPosition
    |> (fun p -> try moveByLengthAndAngle x1 a1 p with ex -> failwith "failed moveByLengthAndAngle")
    |> (fun p -> try moveByXandY x2 y2 p with ex -> failwith "failed moveByXandY")
    |> (fun p -> try moveByXandAngle x3 a3 p with ex -> failwith "failed moveByXandAngle")
    |> (fun p -> try moveByLengthAndAngle x4 a4 p with ex -> failwith "failed moveByLengthAndAngle")
    // etc...
```

Behold the power of expression oriented programming :).

Unfortunately, if you're pipelining over a sequence it becomes much more difficult as:

1. What happens in the pipeline (for Seqs) is composition, not execution.
2. Exception handling inside an IEnumerable is undefined and so depends on the implementation of the Enumerator.

The only safe way is to make sure the internals of each sequence operation are wrapped.

Edit: Wow, I can't believe I messed that up. It's fixed now but I do think that the two other solutions are cleaner.

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't know you could simply wrap pipelined calls with try-with (I'm still rather new to F# and it shows). Also Seqs are not a problem, the question title is probably misleading as I meant "pipelined sequence of calls", my English needs improvement as well :-)

Comment: That's one of the great things about F#! Because everything is an expression, you can put anything (almost) anywhere.

Comment: It's nice that you are able to do this, but this code smells. If method A throws, throw. If method B throws, throw. This is just covering up the fact that the exceptions thrown by these methods are not detailed enough. Would you do this everywhere you used these methods?

Comment: @RobertJeppesen these methods are primitives, they can tell you things like "the first argument is invalid because is negative". On the other hand, within the pipeline I know that I called the primitive with a given goal, and can add information to the exception, for ex. throwing "wall length cannot be negative" (because I know that I used the primitive to compute something on a wall). So I can check every operation and provide a more meaningful error message than the one thrown by the primitive. I'm open to suggestions for improvement though!

Comment: I've just realized with another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263115/why-does-pattern-matching-fail-on-an-exception-in-this-case that this is not going to work in fact (at least not the way I was expecting).

Comment: Gah, don't I feel like an idiot.  Sorry for the confusion, I fixed it to actually do what I intended before.

Comment: Don't worry my understanding of F# has improved thanks to this!

Answer (score 2):

I am unclear why

> Now the new requirement is to introduce exception handling. A big
>   try/with around the whole operation chain is not enough because I'd
>   like to know which line caused the exception. I need to know which
>   argument is invalid, so that the user knows what parameter must be
>   changed.

the debugger isn't sufficient for this.  This sounds like a design-time bug in the user's code; each of these methods might throw ArgumentException and nothing would handle it (it would crash the app), and the programmer would debug and see the method/stack that threw the exception, and the exception text would have the argument name.

(Or maybe this is FSI/scripting typically?)

Comment: Each argument for the move operations is specified by the user in the GUI. For ex. x1 could be "WallLength". At some point the engine could receive a negative value for WallLength, and attempting a move by that length raises an exception. What I want then is to raise an exception saying "Wall Length cannot be negative", which is handled by the caller and displayed to the user. If another move in the sequence uses a different argument, for ex. WallHeight, the exception should say "Wall Height cannot be negative".

Comment: p.s. sorry maybe I get what is the source of confusion. When I say "which line caused the exception" I don't mean line number, I mean which operation in the pipeline.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification.  Yes, if this is about communicating the info at runtime to the user via a UI, then Rick's solution looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the exception handling in the function calls and throw them. Wouldn't this break the code. Then in your function that calls this, catch the error and display to user.

Comment: That is not sufficient because the functions do not know the name of what was provided as argument. For ex. in my code the first call to moveByLengthAndAngle receives x1, while the last one receives x4.