# Why does pattern matching fail on an exception in this case?

Tags: f#

I have this simple exception hierarchy:

```
type FirstLevelException(msg) = inherit System.Exception (msg)
type SecondLevelException(msg, inner) = inherit System.Exception (msg, inner)
type ThirdLevelException(msg, inner) = inherit System.Exception (msg, inner)
```

and these three (dummy) functions:

```
member this.FirstFunction a =
    raise (new FirstLevelException("one"))

member this.SecondFunction a =
    try
        this.FirstFunction a
    with
    | :? FirstLevelException as ex -> raise (new SecondLevelException("two", ex))

member this.ThirdFunction a =
    try
        this.SecondFunction 25
    with
    | :? SecondLevelException as ex -> raise (new ThirdLevelException("three", ex))
```

It's easy to see that when you call ThirdFunction:

- firstFunction raises a FirstLevelException
- secondFunction catches it, wraps it into a SecondLevelException and throws it
- thirdFunction catches it, wraps it into a ThirdLevelException and throws it
- the caller can catch a ThirdLevelException.

All good. Now I change thirdFunction in the following way:

```
member this.ThirdFunction a =
    25 |>
    try
        this.SecondFunction
    with
    | :? SecondLevelException as ex -> raise (new ThirdLevelException("three", ex))
```

things become weird: it looks like the pattern matching within ThirdFunction does not work anymore, and the SecondLevelException is propagated all the way up to the ThirdFunction caller, without being wrapped in a ThirdLevelException.

I'm sure there is a logical explanation that my C#-deformed mind can't see. Can someone please shed some light?

Comment: It looks like you're overusing exceptions... have you considered modeling this as discriminated unions instead?

Comment: you're right but this is just a dummy sample to show the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you described is correct - when you write `25 |> expr`, the code in `expr` is evaluated and the result (a function) is then called with `25` as the argument.

In your case, the result of `expr` is a function and the evaluation of the expression (that returns the function) is protected by your `try` block. However, once the function is returned, it escapes the `try` block and the call is made outside of the exception handler.

To move the exception handling *inside* this returned function, you would have to write something like this:

```
25 |> (fun n ->
  try 
    // You need to call the function (i.e. give it something as an argument)
    // inside the try-with block, otherwise it won't be executed here!
    this.SecondFunction n
  with 
  | :? SecondLevelException as ex -> raise (new ThirdLevelException("three", ex)))
```

Nobody would write this kind of code in practice, but I hope it demonstrates the problem!

BTW: I suppose this is related to your earlier SO question about handling exceptions in a pipeline. I [added answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249744/exception-handling-in-pipeline-sequence/8263228#8263228), which may help you understand the problem. (The problem is that wrapping operations of the pipeline in `try .. with` won't prevent exceptions that happen *inside* the pipelined functions).

Comment: Click! I knew it was logical! Thanks!